# How do I `unnest` two incompatible nested tibble columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a column of nested tibbles. I'd like to transform the `x` value of the second row into a list so that I can unnest. How can I change the values of this nested list conditional on the column name (`x`) and it's format (`character`)?

```r
tibble(data = c(tibble(x = list(NULL)), 
                 tibble(x = ""))) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> Error: Can't combine `..1$data` <list> and `..2$data` <character>.
```

Comment: Try this `tibble(data = c(tibble(x = list(NULL)), tibble(x = ""))) %>% unnest_wider(data)`

Comment: Last function is from `tidyr`!

Answer (score 3):

@Duck's comment worked for me.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(data = c(tibble(x = list(NULL)), tibble(x = ""))) %>% 
unnest_wider(data)
```

Let me try to explain:

`tidy::unnest()` struggles to unnest tibbles that have more than one level of nesting. Unnest_wider is capable of "rectangling" which the tidyverse website describes as "the art and craft of taking a deeply nested list (often sourced from wild caught JSON or XML) and taming it into a tidy data set of rows and columns."

Unnest_wider takes each element of a list-column and makes a new column.

Comment: This no longer works as of 2022/4. `> tibble(data = c(tibble(x = list(NULL)), tibble(x = ""))) %>% 
+     tidyr::unnest_wider(data)
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
Error in `col_to_wide()`:
! Can't combine `..1$...1` <list> and `x$...1` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(data = c(
  tibble(x = list(NULL)),
  tibble(x = "")
)) |>
  mutate(data = ifelse(is.list(data),
    data,
    list(data)
  )) |>
  unnest(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

in a tibble where a specific column contains "character" and "list" entries try this:
`lapply(column1, function(x) {if (is.list(x)) x else list(x)})`